# Trigger WordPress Actions from Email?

Tags: email, wp-mail

I have built a sort of marketplace platform based on WordPress and I would like to build a few email-related functionalities to keep the platform easier to use and make it cleaner.

Examples of this are sending the user an email 30 days after they posted a listing and asking them whether it is still current (and giving the option to click a link to delete it if not) or offering a yes/no mechanism (i.e. I already have a mechanism that uses `wp_mail()` to let a user know that someone else is interested in their listing and send that user's details, so I'd like to add two links to that email that have WordPress send a confirmation or rejection notice to the user that triggered the original email).

I spend quite some time googling and didn't find any information on this.

For deleting posts it'd be pretty easy to put in a `get_delete_post_link()` to the email, but I'm not sure how to pass the `$post_ID` and how to have the thing be sent out 30 days later.

Are such things possible with just WordPress or would I need to add an email system to it in order to work?

Comment: Have you looked into [wp_schedule_event](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_schedule_event/) ?

Answer (score 3):

You can solve it like this:

1. use wp_schedule_event to check if any user needs to get the mail
2. if yes, send the mail containing a link like

> yoursite.com/?user_id=99&myaction=yes&mytoken=sometokenforsecurity

Save that token to the user´s user_meta

```
    add_user_meta( $user_id, 'mytoken', $token, true )
```

In your case you obviously need a second link with action=no or whatever you want to call it

3. to catch that link you can use "template_redirect" like this:

   ```
   add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_callback' );


   function my_callback() {
     // check if variables are sent
     if ( ! $user_id = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'user_id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) )
          return;
     if ( ! $action = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'myaction' ) )
           return;
     if ( ! $token = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'mytoken' ) )
           return;
     // check if token is valid
     $saved_token = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'mytoken', true );
     if (!empty($saved_token) && $saved_token == $token) {
           // do the action 
           // delete the token
           delete_user_meta($user_id, 'mytoken');
     }
     // redirect the user to a confirmation page so he knows it worked or did not
     wp_redirect( get_home_url().'/my-confirmation-page');

   }
   ```

Hope that helps!